# On $routeChangeStart location doesn't find the corresponding template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a web application and an `app` variable with the module `myApp`.
I have 3 pages: `/login`, `/registration` and `/`. My `$routeChangeStart` is defined to behave like follows:

1. Check if a global variable `user` is defined, if yes go to step `4`
2. Check where the user wants to go: if he doesn't want to go in `/login` or `/registration` do an `event.preventDefault()` and check if there is a valid session (via cookie) and try to authorize the user. If the user is authorized set the `user` global variable and redirect him to the page he wanted, otherwise send him to the `/login` page.
3. If he wants to go to either on `/login` or `/registration` do nothing (we are in the case no user variable and I want to login or register).
4. Check where the user wants to go: if he wants to go in `/login` or `/registration` do an `event.preventDefault()` and redirect him to the home `/` page (the user has a valid session, no need to login again).

The logic works well, until we hit `F5` (I know it wipes the `$rootScope`, but at the cost of an extra AJAX call we should be fine with it) while in the `/` page with a valid session cookie. The application simply doesn't redirect to the correct template, the page remains blank. If we instead insert in the URL anything beside `/` (e.g. `/blah`) everything works fine.

Here's my `app.js`:

```
(function () {
    angular.module("myApp", ["controllers", "services", "directives", "ngRoute"])
        .config(["$httpProvider", "$routeProvider", function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

            $routeProvider
                .when("/login", {
                    controller: "LoginController",
                    templateUrl: "app/partials/login.html"
                })
                .when("/registration", {
                    controller: "RegistrationController",
                    templateUrl: "app/partials/registration.html"
                })
                .when("/", {
                    controller: "MainController",
                    templateUrl: "app/partials/home.html"
                })
                .otherwise("/");

        }])
        .run(function ($rootScope, $location, $http) {
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

                if (!$rootScope.user) {

                    if (next && next.$$route && (next.$$route.originalPath !== "/login" && next.$$route.originalPath !== "/registration")) {
                        event.preventDefault();

                        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/user?self=true")
                            .success(function (data) {
                                $rootScope.user = data;
                                $location.path(next.$$route.originalPath);
                            })
                            .error(function () {
                                $location.path("/login");
                            });
                    }
                }else{
                    if (next && next.$$route && (next.$$route.originalPath === "/login" || next.$$route.originalPath === "/registration")){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $location.path("/");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    angular.module("controllers", []);
    angular.module("services", []);
    angular.module("directives", [])
})();
```

Why doesn't the `$location.path(next.$$route.originalPath);` in the `.success()` AJAX call work? Note that if I substitute it with e.g. `$location.path("/blah");` it is redirected correctly (but still doesn't work with `$location.path("/");`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when you call event.preventDefault() angular tries to fallback into current path. However, in case you are entering for the first time, current path is undefined and so angular puts the root path("/") as the current path. Doing so, $location.path tries to go in the same place where angular brought you, ending up in doing nothing.

So, finally you have to do a $route.reload() and not a $location.path().

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/user?self=true")
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $rootScope.user = data;
                            if ($location.path() === next.$$route.originalPath) {
                                $route.reload();
                            } else {
                                $location.path(next.$$route.originalPath);
                            }
                        })
                        .error(function () {
                            $location.path("/login");
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
    $location.path('/c');
});`

This should work fine. 
Note: 
`event.preventDefault();` will only function in Angular 1.3+ but you can't change $location directly, needs $evalAsync

Comment: Already tried it, the behaviour is exactly the same... I run `angular 1.3.15` btw (and same version of `angular-route` of course). But a question arises: has the `c` in `/c` have some meaning or its random? Because with `/c` works, but its just a workaround like the `/blah` I tried. I need to send the user to the `next.$$route.originalPath` location...

Comment: Did you output the ```next.$$route.originalPath```  ?
Did you try with $apply?

Comment: Yes, the location is correct (`/`, debugged with chrome) and yes with no result (actually with an exception because we are already inside the digest cycle)

Comment: ```$location.path('/')``` will fail inside ```'$routeChangeStart'``` 
Try another existing location to see if it works.

Comment: tried `/home` (I changed it also in the `$routeProvider`) but the result is the same.

Comment: Try using $stateProvider instead of $route. I found it much more reliable

Comment: Did you try $location.url()?

Comment: ```/home``` and ```\``` are the same thing. Only reason it wouldn't work is your changing to same path, or another error. I have implemented the same as you did and works

Comment: It was as you guessed, I was changing to the same path and thus the `$location` wasn't doing nothing. The solution proposed by @Sandro resolved my issue.